# How to release class instances and memory?

Tags: java, swing, jprofiler

I am using JProfiler to troubleshoot my swing based desktop application for memory issues. In Memory view of JProfiler, I see **40K** **instances** of a class and using **3MB of memory**.

```
DefaultTableModel summaryModel = null;

void insertEnv(final Map<String, String> configMap,final String variable,final String value)
{
    this.configMap = configMap;

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {               
            Vector dataVector  = summaryModel.getDataVector();

            for(int row = 0; dataVector != null && row < dataVector.size(); row++)
            {
                Vector rowData = (Vector)dataVector.get(row);
                if(rowData.get(0).toString().equals(variable))
                {
                    summaryModel.removeRow(row);
                }
            }

            Object[] row = new Object[] {variable, value };
            summaryModel.addRow(row);               
        }
    };

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
}
```

In insertEnv() function, I am adding new row in a JTable. This function is called 40K times and thus 40K instances of above class. What can be done to release the memory and instance count?

Comment: What class are you talking about?

Comment: Are you sure there actually is a memory problem? To start with, 3MB of memory is nothing for a Java app. Can you verify that the 40k objects do not eventually get garbage-collected? From the source code you show, these Runnables do not seem to have anything that would cause them to stick around forever, and they themselves do not grab huge amounts of data. JProfiler can show you memory statistics for only "live" objects, I believe. Does that include them?

Comment: Yes, I second @Thilo, 3MB is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure properly close everything engine need to close?

You write "add from event new row to JTable" which seems to be bad pattern, but code use kind of model, can bee good.

JTable with very big data sets can/should be used in "virtual" mode. Look at google.
4MB of RAM usually isn't a problem, but collecting garbage 40k "pieces of objects" may be hard :(

Comment: Will try to implement JTable in virtual mode :) Might use pagination here.